# Get byte[] from Cloudinary URL

Tags: cloudinary

I've got the Cloudinary URL of an image, I need to get the `byte[]` of that image.  How can I do this using the Cloudinary API?

Comment: Did you try to read documentation?

Comment: Yes... and i don´t see how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary image URLs are publicly available and therefore can be downloaded using a simple GET request probably by any programing language.

Cloudinary's GEM has such method implemented. You can use it or implement something similar on your own: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/blob/master/lib/cloudinary/downloader.rb